# Implementing Maybe type using enum

Tags: swift, generics

My definition of `Maybe` enum:

```
enum Maybe<A> {
    case Nothing
    case Just(A)
}
```

Printing a `Just` value works perfectly:

```
print(Maybe.Just(10))
```

**Output**:

```
 swiftc -o main main.swift
 ./main
Just(10)
```

However, fails in case of a `Nothing` value:

`print(Maybe.Nothing)`

**Output**:

```
error: argument type 'Maybe<_>' does not conform to expected type 'Any'
```

What's happening, here ?
Could someone give me some background information about this issue and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `Maybe.Nothing`. There's no such type as `Maybe`, only `Maybe<A>`.

Whenever declaring a variable of type `Maybe`, you need to specify its generic type parameter, even in case of `Nothing`.

```
let noInt = Maybe<Int>.Nothing
```

Unrelated to your question, but enum cases should be lowerCamelCase. You should also give meaningful names to generic type parameters instead of using single letters.

```
enum Maybe<Value> {
    case nothing
    case just(Value)
}
```

It seems you are trying to reimplement the existing `Optional` type. If you're doing this as a learning exercise, it might be worth actually looking at the [implementation of `Optional`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/10a4e1eac4c6f7d9cb93bc8394f36675dc4c0a30/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L122) for best-practices.